# Toggling Boolean Prop Value

Tags: javascript, vue-component, toggle, vuetify.js, prop

I'm using a boolean prop to to indicate if a Vue component is disabled or not, but I would like to controle it via a button to change it from default of `false` to `true` when the button is clicked. Here's the code I have, but it's not working.

```
  <v-tooltip v-model="show" top>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn
                id="editable"
                icon
                v-on="on"
                @click="toggle()"
            >
             <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <span>Edit</span>
    </v-tooltip>

props: {
editable: Boolean,
},
data() {
    return {
        editable: false
    }
 },
mounted(){
},
methods:{
    toggle(){
        if(this.editable){
            this.$emit('sendValue', $event.editable.false)
        }else{
            this.$emit('sendValue', $event.editable.true)
        }
    }
},
```

so when the `v-btn "editable"` is clicked, the `editable` prop value is changed from false to true, so on and so forth.

Any suggentions?

Comment: `@click="toggle()"` <=> `toggle(editable)`  You're not passing in an argument.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that, but it's not working though.

Comment: `editable` is a data property.  Why do you need to pass it in?

Comment: well, I want it to be updated.

Comment: But it's on the component.  It's within scope.  You already have access to it.

Comment: updated my code, still not working.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `this.editable = !this.editable;`?

Comment: where in the code exactly? I would think in the `@click="this.editable = !this.editable"`?

Comment: Possibly there, or in the `toggle` method

Comment: you should be getting an error on the console, for `editable` is both a prop and a data. If you mutate the prop from what would you need a data attribute for?

Comment: @ffflabs that's exactly what I need help with.

Comment: I feel like some more context is needed to understand what you're trying to achieve. You place your `editable` as the id in your v-btn. What's the goal?